# Long duration video not working in Exo player

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer-media-item

I have used exoplayer in my app for video playing. Everthing working fine but a video with resolution 1920×1040 and duration 41hr is not playing not even app crashing but getting the errors Following is my source code and then error

```java
public class vPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int pos;
    private static List<Video> allVideos;
    private PlayerView playerView;
    private static ExoPlayer exoPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vplayer);
        allVideos = videoList;
        Intent videoIntent = getIntent();
        pos = videoIntent.getIntExtra("position",0);
        exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(allVideos.get(pos).getUri());
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri);
        exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        exoPlayer.prepare();
        exoPlayer.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        exoPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error :

E/LoadTask: Unexpected exception loading stream

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Top bit not zero: -47086724
    at androidx.media3.common.util.ParsableByteArray.readUnsignedLongToLong(ParsableByteArray.java:408)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.AtomParsers.parseTkhd(AtomParsers.java:836)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.AtomParsers.parseTrak(AtomParsers.java:294)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.AtomParsers.parseTraks(AtomParsers.java:134)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.processMoovAtom(Mp4Extractor.java:517)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.processAtomEnded(Mp4Extractor.java:476)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.readAtomPayload(Mp4Extractor.java:458)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.read(Mp4Extractor.java:256)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.read(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:129)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1040)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:652)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:628)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$UnexpectedLoaderException: Unexpected IllegalStateException: Top bit not zero: -47086724
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:435)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Top bit not zero: -47086724
    at androidx.media3.common.util.ParsableByteArray.readUnsignedLongToLong(ParsableByteArray.java:408)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.AtomParsers.parseTkhd(AtomParsers.java:836)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.AtomParsers.parseTrak(AtomParsers.java:294)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.AtomParsers.parseTraks(AtomParsers.java:134)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.processMoovAtom(Mp4Extractor.java:517)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.processAtomEnded(Mp4Extractor.java:476)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.readAtomPayload(Mp4Extractor.java:458)
    at androidx.media3.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.read(Mp4Extractor.java:256)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.read(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:129)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1040)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```